# HTML on Firefox doesn't display well

Tags: html, css

Here is a piece of HTML that does not display well in Firefox (10)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            .block6 { float: left; margin: 0 10px; width: 460px; }
            .block { position: relative; }
            .block:after {
                clear: both;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
            }
            header { margin-bottom: 40px; }
            .wie { text-align: center; }
            .w {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0 10px;
                text-align: left;
                width: 960px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="wie">
                <div class="w">
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="block6">
                            aa
                        </div>
                        <div class="block6">
                            bb
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- block -->
                </div> <!-- w -->
            </div> <!-- wie -->
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that an "extra" space on the top is displayed.
If I set:

```
header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The extra space disappears.
I think the error is in the block or block6 class. Any suggestion?

In Chrome displays well.

---

EDIT:

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/wARzA/

Comment: A link to a working example would probably help you get a response.

Comment: A method that will tend to get you consistent results across browsers is to use a CSS reset, such as the one provided by Yahoo ([YIU](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)) or [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).  This won't fix problems and has a few small challenges of it's own, but it brings the browsers onto a much more level playing field for CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd bug, but many things like setting a top border make the bug disappear. Perhaps the cleanest way is this:

```
header { min-height: 1px; }
```

Comment: That works! So it's a bug... I spent 4 hours cutting the code of the page looking for mistakes. And... It's a bug. :| Thank you very very very very much!

Comment: I was going to ask what caused the bug but looks like Jacob explains it well... unless that's a red herring??

Comment: I've filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=734279.  Hopefully it will get addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue.  The header has a bottom margin of `40px`.  The content inside is all floated, so the header never occupies any height.  That's why the *bottom* margin appears on top.

Replacing the margin with padding works.   [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5R7j/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But See this http://jsfiddle.net/wARzA/ the content **has a height**!

Comment: Even if I add `<div style="clear: both"></div>` at the end in the `<div class="block"> ... </div>`, so it does not contain only floating elements, the error persists.